# Can I "transplant" a ClickOnce application from one PC to another?

Tags: installation, clickonce

My wife's old work computer has a ClickOnce-deployed app on it that she now needs on her new work computer.  (It runs on her old computer fine, but her old computer doesn't run fine at all, hence the new one.)

The source distribution for the app is long gone; it was hosted on the workstation of an employee who left long ago.

Can the app be moved to her new PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a simply copy and paste of the app from the old computer to the new one? Are they running the same OS? It can be a little awkward finding the exact location of ClickOnce apps, but it can be done, of course. Do you need to move saved data as well? That could be trickier, but using [FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) and/or [RegMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx) should cover most bases.